# A framework, error show: Undefined symbols and Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, linker, frameworks

I stuck with this issue. I create a framework with several third part libraries. I import the framework to testApp, but always compile error as following:

```
Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'CoreAudioTypes': framework 'CoreAudioTypes' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Undefined symbols:
Moya.MoyaError.underlying(Moya.MoyaError.Type) -> (Swift.Error, Moya.Response?) -> Moya.MoyaError, referenced from:
      closure #1 (Moya.Endpoint, (Swift.Result<Foundation.URLRequest, Moya.MoyaError>) -> ()) -> () in variable initialization expression of MinimaxOpenVoiceCallSDK.(requestClosure in _CD0D6BAD689FE3F292250BBCE8E983FC) : (Moya.Endpoint, (Swift.Result<Foundation.URLRequest, Moya.MoyaError>) -> ()) -> () in MinimaxOpenVoiceCallSDK[8](NetworkManager.o)
  dispatch thunk of Moya.MoyaProvider.request(_: A, callbackQueue: __C.OS_dispatch_queue?, progress: ((Moya.ProgressResponse) -> ())?, completion: (Swift.Result<Moya.Response, Moya.MoyaError>) -> ()) -> Moya.Cancellable, referenced from:
      MinimaxOpenVoiceCallSDK.NetWorkRequest(_: Moya.TargetType, needShowFailAlert: Swift.Bool, successCallback: (MinimaxOpenVoiceCallSDK.ResponseModel) -> (), failureCallback: ((MinimaxOpenVoiceCallSDK.ResponseModel) -> ())?) -> Moya.Cancellable? in MinimaxOpenVoiceCallSDK[8](NetworkManager.o)
  method descriptor for Moya.TargetType.validationType.getter : Moya.ValidationType, referenced from:
      l_got.$s4Moya10TargetTypeP010validationC0AA010ValidationC0OvgTq in MinimaxOpenVoiceCallSDK[14](APIRun.o)
  dispatch thunk of Moya.TargetType.sampleData.getter : Foundation.Data, referenced from:
      merged closure #2 () -> Moya.EndpointSampleResponse in closure #1 (Moya.TargetType) -> Moya.Endpoint in variable initialization expression of MinimaxOpenVoiceCallSDK.(myEndpointClosure in _CD0D6BAD689FE3F292250BBCE8E983FC) : (Moya.TargetType) -> Moya.Endpoint in MinimaxOpenVoiceCallSDK[8](NetworkManager.o)
  method descriptor for Moya.TargetType.sampleData.getter : Foundation.Data, referenced from:
      l_got.$s4Moya10TargetTypeP10sampleData10Foundation0E0VvgTq in MinimaxOpenVoiceCallSDK[14](APIRun.o)
```

Anyone has idea how to fix this issue?

Do I miss any configuration should be set